# sas adding sheets to existing excel file formatting error

Tags: sas, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I use SAS EG 6.1 to add sheets to an existing excel file (xlsx). I use a simple proc export with DBMS=xlsx. The data is written to the excelfile succesfully.

However it appears that formatting in Excel is taken from the already existing sheets. There also is a difference between cells that contains numbers vs. cells that contain text. For instance when in the existing sheet i used header 1 cell style, the numbers in the exported worksheets also had this header 1 style.

Screenshot of the existing sheet: [Existing Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmW0N.jpg) 
Screenshot of the added sheet (wrong formats)
[The wrongly formatted added worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWmXn.jpg)

I tried the following things:
- add an extra sheet without formatting and place this as first sheet in the workbook. My thought was the exported work sheets then wouldn't have the format either. No succes.
- add an extra sheet without formatting and place this as **last** sheet in the workbook. My thought was the exported work sheets then wouldn't have the format either. No succes.

2 alternative possible solutions i think of are:
1) using the pcfiles and ranges method. I will try this and post the results.
2) recreate the existing workbook and pray to see different results.

Did anyone have this experience and solved this problem?

update 17-1-2016: added screenshots and tried the procedure with a fresh excel workfile. The latter didn't result in succes.

Comment: This would most likely be an issue with Excel, not something that SAS could control. That being said, I'm having a hard time understanding what's happening, can you post some screen shots?

Comment: You can also give the code in this paper a shot. It's based on VBS so it may get around some of the other issues. I have no idea how it works/integrates into SAS EG, but it works well with Base SAS. http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Poor/Rich_SAS_Users_Proc_Export

Comment: Thanks @Reeza, i will give the macro a try and report back on my findings. I added some screenshots to clarify my problem.